# Codeigniter 3.1.16 routing issues

Tags: codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

I'm having some troubles with routing in codeigniter.
My routing file is as below:

```
$route['admin/newgallery'] = 'gallery/do_upload';
$route['admin/listgallery'] = 'gallery/list';
$route['admin/create'] = 'posts/create';
$route['admin/listposts'] = 'posts/list';
$route['admin'] = 'admin/index';
$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/view/$1';
$route['posts'] = 'posts/index';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/index';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/index/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

All routes work just fine except for the first two:

```
$route['admin/newgallery'] = 'gallery/do_upload';
$route['admin/listgallery'] = 'gallery/list';
```

When I type `mypage/admin/listgallery` it calls `gallery/list` correctly. The problem is when I type the address with the original controller/method (in this case gallery/list) it goes to the list page as well when it should call a 404 error! Every other routing rule I have set does that, except the first two!

Comment: Explain what is "orignal controller/method".

Comment: I mean that

https://mysyte/admin/listgallery and https://mysyte/gallery/list goes to the list page when https://mysyte/gallery/list was supposed to go to the error page!

Comment: Your assumptions are incorrect - if you have a controller/method you call directly, of course it will work. It has nothing to do with the routing. You seem to think that the routing magically overrides the normal operation, and as you have observed, it doesn't. So what is it that you think you are trying achieve?

Comment: If you want to override original controller/method/param call, you should make it with Apache (usually .htaccess) file. Check rewrite and redirect rules.

Comment: The routes.php file is used to set custom routes, right? If my assumption is incorrect this file gets completely useless!

Comment: Tpojka, every other routing rules I set does right, except the first two so I guess it's not low level config!

Comment: @GianpaoloBarci So am I right in saying that you only want access to any method/controller via the routes table... With any direct access to result in a error 404 or the like? Out of the BOX CI lets you directly access any existing method/controller AND let you create custom routes...

Comment: @TimBrownlaw YES!!!! That's what I want! All other custom routes are doing correctly except these two I mentioned! I need this because they ar for admin use and admin use only! They need to be protected from outside access! =D

Comment: It can be done - just working on an example for you now... BUT if these particular controller/methods are Admin ONLY, wouldn't you test for admin access in the controller? Using a Route and calling it admin doesn't make it protected from "outside" users... You would want to call it through the admin controller itself and exclude direct access via the URL.

Comment: @GianpaoloBarci Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the Box, Codeigniter allows you to directly access any Controller/Method from the URL.

It also provides the creation of custom routes so you could have 10 or more urls all pointing at the same controller/method with parameter passing if that was your desire...

So in the case you ONLY want access to any Controller/Method that are defiend in the Routes config.

You need to test if the url is defined in the routes config array.

The main code is something like...

```
$this->load->helper('url');
if(!isset($this->router->routes[uri_string()])){
    show_404(); // Or whatever you want ...
}
```

And you would put this in your controller's constructor you want to protect.

Of course you could create a common controller and extend those controllers you want to protect in this manner.

( NOT Recommended ) Or if you want to get really "hacky" you could put it in the system/core/controller constructor and make it system wide. SO Everything needs to be defined in a route. 
**NOTE:** This breaks the 'default_controller'.